# Problem with Testing Hibernet using Junit in Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, junit

I want to test the Spring data layer
I have basic `@Entity` Products:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class Product{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "i_user")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;
```

I have `ProductRepository` Repository:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {

}
```

And I have test `ProductTest`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class ProductTest{

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository  productRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        List<Product> users = productRepository.findAll();

        assertThat(users).hasSize(1);

    }
}
```

And I have this error:

```
18:53:15.926 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class com.ProductTest]
18:53:15.942 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
18:53:15.954 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
18:53:15.987 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.ProductTest] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper]
18:53:16.012 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.ProductTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
18:53:16.020 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.ProductTest]: class path resource [com/ProductTest-context.xml] does not exist
18:53:16.021 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.ProductTest]: class path resource [com/ProductTestContext.groovy] does not exist
18:53:16.022 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.ProductTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
18:53:16.023 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.ProductTest]: ProductTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
18:53:16.134 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.ProductTest]
```

Comment: which Spring boot version are you using?

Comment: I using this version `2.1.4.RELEASE`

Comment: Do you inject Entity instance? Is it a typo

Comment: try @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository instead of private Product productRepository;.

Comment: I made mistakes in writing posts. I using `ProductRepository`.
That is not a problem.